# How to pass array in jquery ajax call and how to receive same from spring mvc controller

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am calling spring mvc controller method using jquery ajax.

jquery ajax call:

```
    var filters = {KPI : visual, partnerName: params['partnerName'], itemQualifier: getItemQualifier(), currency : getCurrency(), sellSide: getSellSide()};

$.ajax({                                                                    
 type: "POST",
 url: "/reports/savefilters",
 data: filters,
 success: function(response){
     alert('success: ' + response);
 },
 error: function(e){
    alert('Error: ' + e.message);
 }
});
```

Spring mvc code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/savefilters",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public void saveFilters(@RequestParam("KPI") String KPI,    @RequestParam("partnerName") String partnerName,
    @RequestParam("itemQualifier") String itemQualifier, @RequestParam("currency") String currency, 
    @RequestParam("sellSide") String sellSide){
           System.out.println("saveFilters");
}
```

Its working fine without "@RequestParam("partnerName") String partnerName" parameter.

Here "params['partnerName']" values are like abc,def,ghi.

Am I not sending data properly to controller??? 
Any suggestions how to make it work???. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
@RequestParam("partnerName") String partnerName
```

to

```
@RequestParam(value = "partnerName[]", required = false) String[] partnerName
```

Comment: It works fine when partnerName array is not empty. If the array is empty then it shows "String[] parameter 'partnerName[]' is not present" error.

Comment: @Hemachandra Use attribute `required` in `@RequestParam`, check my updated answer please.

Comment: Thanks @10086. It works as expected with these changes

Comment: Just one more doubt... I need to pass around 8 parameters and out of them 4 arrays are there. I don't think its proper to pass these many arguments to a method. I am thinking best solution is to use one json object which includes all these parameters. Is this proper to pass as json Object???

Comment: @Hemachandra No, not as JSON Object, you should define a `class` to do this.

Comment: I tried to do that. jackson-mapper-asl is used to map json object with a class. but it didn't go well for me. May I raise separate question for that???

Comment: @Hemachandra I think you should do more search on Google or check more manuals for Spring, then if you really do not make it, ask a new question.

Comment: Sure will do that. once again thanks for all the help @10086

Comment: Damn, was searching for ages: I didn't know that if i pass in the data part: data: {organisations: ["some", "string", "array"]}, that I have to name the request param organisations[] (WITH brackets).